# Z-index broken in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, z-index

This code works in every other browser I've tried, except IE8.

IE8 appears to ignore the z-index - and the pop-up becomes a pop-under.

It's in the right place, just renders underneath the thumbnail.

Anyone?

Thanks!

HTML:

```html
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
    <img src="comic_a3_thumb.jpg" height="300" width="212" border="0"
         style="float:right; margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;"
         alt="description" />
    <span>
        <img src="/images/comic_a3_popup.jpg" />
    </span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```css
.thumbnail{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    padding: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
    border-width: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
    visibility: visible;
    top: -140px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
    left: -500px;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simple answer is to add a `z-index` value that is greater than the `.thumbnail:hover` value to the hover state of the `span`.

```
.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
    visibility: visible;
    top: -140px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
    left: -500px;
    z-index: 51;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Put these lines in your page head

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style>
            #your_faulty_div{
            background-color:#000; /*any color it doesn't matter*/
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        }
        </style>
<![endif]-->
```

your_faulty_div is the div which is misbehaving due to IE z-index bug.

Works smooth , i use it in all of my projects where i have positioned elements overlaping.

Comment: What do you mean misbehaving? Is it the div thats supposed to go on top, or the one supposed to go behind? Giving it an opacity of 0 will hide it all together? I have problems with a similar issue myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want the `span` to show above the element marked as the thumbnail. You have not specified the `z-index` for the `span` element. Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Pop-up Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #vbox {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 200px;
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #vbox:hover #hbox {
            display: block;
        }

        #hbox {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            display: none;
            height: 200px;
            left: 50px;
            position: relative;
            top: 50px;
            width: 200px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="vbox">
        <p>Hover over this box to show a hidden "pop-up".</p>
        <p id="hbox">This box is a pop-up.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix this issue is by adding a class to the thumbnail image like this:

```
.thumbnail:hover img.thumb {z-index:-50; position:relative;}
```