# IE 7 z-index issue on Nav Dropdowns

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, z-index

Can anyone tell me why on IE 8 the main (top) navigations sub-menues (specifically on the "Master Cleanse" dropdown) get hidden under the sidebar and content boxes on this page?: http://therawfoodsite.com/newsite/store/

Seems to work fine in all other browsers (of course) and I have the z-index setup correctly...IE just doesn't like it. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290191/z-index-broken-in-ie8/2839373#2839373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is being forced into "IE7 Mode". Check the HTTP response headers returned by your page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
..
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
..
```

You can easily fix your problem *in IE8/9* by removing that HTTP header.

If that's not an option, or you need to support genuine IE7..

On `.menu-main-container`, add `position: relative; z-index: 51`.

If you'd like more information about this IE6/7 bug, see: [IE7 Z-Index issue - Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229184/ie7-z-index-issue-context-menu/6229309#6229309)