# Hyperlink not working on <img> tag inside <a> tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with this code:

```
         <div class="box_c rounded">
            <a class="box_int rounded" href="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="careers">
                    <span class="ico_boton">
                        <img src="img/spacer.gif" width="28" alt="Spacer"/>
                    </span>
                    <h5>Text</h5>
                    <p>Text</p>
                </div>
            </a>
         </div>
```

In IE9, Firefox and Chrome all the area is clickable, but in IE8 the img area appears as clickable and the url appears too, but the hyperlink don't do nothing. What Can I do? I tried with z-index but it don't do nothing.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `<div>` is a block element and therefore shouldn't be contained inside an anchor element.

Comment: A div, span, h5 and a p shouldn't go inside an `a` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. What is the best that I can't do? transform the anchor to div, and open the hyperlink with javascript?

Comment: In HTML5, It's valid to insert a block element like `p` inside a link `a`. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html

Comment: Try to make your `a` element as `block`. `.box_int.rounded { display: block; }`.

Comment: Thank frient, but don't works. It seems like I8 is positioning the img to the front.

Comment: No, It's not the reason. It work correctly for me in `IE7+`. I think that it's related to other CSS of your file. If you add the CSS in your question, I can debug it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried validating your code in IE8's Developer Tools? If you're unfamiliar with the process, have a look at [this quick tutorial](http://techie-buzz.com/browsers/how-to-validate-html-css-feed-and-links-in-ie8.html) on how to do it.

Also, are you using `z-index` in your CSS code by any chance? If so, have a look at [this other question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290191/z-index-broken-in-ie8) and also [this detailed article](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) regarding this issue - they both refer to IE8 having a bug when handling `z-index`.