# Z-index not working on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, z-index

The following code works fine in IE 11, but when I test the page on IE8 the bottom of the Main_Box does not overlap the top of the Intro DIV.

If I remove the background colour from "Intro" I can see the bottom of the Main_Box behind it, but I cannot get it to display in front.

I thought it might be the bug referenced on this page...

[Z-index in Internet Explorer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517158/z-index-in-internet-explorer-not-working)

...so tried to wrap it in a Absolute DIV to reset the z-index, but to no avail.

```
    <div style="position: relative; z-index: 3000">
<section id="intro">

    <h1>
        EXAMPLES
    </h1>

    <div class="animation-container">
        <div id="object" class="animate fadeIn"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="intro-copy">
        <img src="./images/arrow.png" alt="Arrow" id="arrow" class="pulse" />
        <p>Scroll down</p>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Working IE11 HTML:

```
<section id="main">

    <div class="Main_Box">
    <h10>
        “People often represent the weakest link in the security chain”
    </h10>

    <h2>
        Contact us today to see how we can help.
    </h2>
    </div>

</section>


<section id="intro">

    <h1>
        EXAMPLES
    </h1>

    <div class="animation-container">
        <div id="object" class="animate fadeIn"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="intro-copy">
        <img src="./images/arrow.png" alt="Arrow" id="arrow" class="pulse" />
        <p>Scroll down</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#main{
height: 420px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 130px;
 }

.Main_Box {
border-width: 5.547px;
border-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
border-style: solid;
border-radius: 10px;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(27,27,27) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(27,27,27) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(27,27,27) 100%);
box-shadow: 2.5px 4.33px 5px 0px rgb( 0, 0, 0 );
position: relative;
width: 70%;
height: 270px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
padding: 30px;
}


#intro{
height: 650px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to my Dev site:

http://goo.gl/NlAkiU

Thanks,

Comment: Already answered [here][1] and [here][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290191/z-index-broken-in-ie8
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156192/internet-explorer-z-index-bug

Comment: Your problem is that you're using IE8.  I know that doesn't sound like much of an answer.  But these are the reasons that most developers have abandoned support for that browser completely.

Comment: Are you using the [HTML5 Shim](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) or similar in your page? HTML5 elements, like `<section>`, [aren't recognized by IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section#Browser_compatibility) without some help.

Comment: Thanks, but I have added some scripts to the HTML head to "fix" the HTML 5 elements

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning z-index at the section level; `#main` and `#intro` are siblings, and consequently are far more likely to be in the same [stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) as far as legacy browsers are concerned.

```
#main { z-index: 9999; }
```